# State array updating on next click

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 state values: `username`, `password` and `address`, and corresponding 3 textboxes where I am including the values in the respective states. Now I want that on click of a submit button, these states should be added on a state array called `add_data`:

state:

```
this.state = {
  uname: '',
  pass: '',
  address:'',
  salary:'',
  add_data:[]
}
```

inputs:

```
<div>
    <label>username:</label>
    <input type="text" noValidate name="uname" onChange={this.changeHandler} />
</div>

<div>
    <label>password:</label>
    <input type="password" noValidate name="pass" onChange={this.changeHandler} />
</div>

<div>
    <label>address:</label>
    <textarea noValidate name="address" onChange={this.changeHandler}></textarea>
</div>

<div>
    <button onClick={this.submitForm}>Edit</button>
</div>
```

click and change functions:

```
changeHandler = e => {
    var adddata_obj;
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
}
submitForm = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
    this.setState({
        add_data: [...this.state.add_data, { username: this.state.uname, password: this.state.pass, address: this.state.address }]
    })
}
```

The problem is that when I click on edit button, the `add_data` array does not update. Instead, when I change something else on the textboxes, it shows the value od edt_data fro the last click. Please help.

Comment: where you are updating `edit_data`? also how you are checking that, it is not getting updated?

Comment: You're not being precise in what exactly is that you want. When you press Edit, you want to see the textarea updated with the new values?

Comment: What is edit_data ? did you mean add_data ?Could you provide us a jsBin example ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're problem is because it doesn't contain enough information.. but if your problem is that your console.log doesn't show the correct content for add_data, that is because you are logging before you setState... But please provide more info  if that is not your problem..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete working code example (test it here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/mq66o03r3j):

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      uname: "",
      pass: "",
      address: "",
      salary: "",
      add_data: []
    };
  }

  changeHandler = e => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  };

  submitForm = () => {
    this.setState({
      add_data: [
        ...this.state.add_data,
        {
          username: this.state.uname,
          password: this.state.pass,
          address: this.state.address
        }
      ],
      uname: "",
      pass: "",
      address: "",
      salary: ""
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>username:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="uname"
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
            value={this.state.uname}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="pass"
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
            value={this.state.pass}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>address:</label>
          <textarea
            name="address"
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
            value={this.state.address}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.submitForm}>Edit</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Saved data:</p>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>User</td>
              <td>Password</td>
              <td>Address</td>
            </tr>
            {this.state.add_data.map(d => (
              <tr>
                <td>{d.username}</td>
                <td>{d.password}</td>
                <td>{d.address}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Now you can find your mistakes by yourself. Don't hesitate to ask me, when something is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine @user3450590, see your snippet here just with the `add_data` being rendered out as a list https://stackblitz.com/edit/state-array-updating-on-next-click.

The only thing I changed was where you log the state. `setSet` is asynchronous ( see [here](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3)), you can pass it a callback as a second argument if you need to log out the changes.

As per @virtusmaior's example you also leave the original values in the state which you may want to change when you submit your form.

Also as a nice little cherry on top your submit function would benefit from [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). ie

```
submitForm = () => {
    console.log(this.state);

    this.setState(state => {
        const { add_data, ...values } = state;
        return {
            add_data: [...add_data, { ...values }]
        };
    });
}
```